can not get .elf file contiki-ng platform simplelink
I followed the instructions for the simplelink-contiki-ng setup in CCS for the hello world example project with no changes but when I build the project I only get a hello-world.simplelink file, nothing else. How do I get the .elf file so I can flash it onto my CC1310 using TIs Flashprogrammer 2 Software?
Makefile is as follows:
CONTIKI_PROJECT = hello-world
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)


    CONTIKI = ../..
    TARGET = simplelink
    BOARD = launchpad/cc1310
    DEBUG = 1
    CFLAGS += -g
    include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include

I tried to add the .elf ending in the ccs-make properties, this only resulted in no rule to make hello-world.elf, tried different platforms like cc26x0-cc13x0 but that only threw way more errors and i just can not find any solution. All the PATH-Variables are proper, I have all the proper programms installed in the right place. Help is appreciated.
This is not about the program code, this is about me only getting a .simplelink file and no .bin .hex or .elf file to upload to the TI CC1310 via the FLASHPROGRAMMER 2.
Here is the code, 1 for 1.
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2006, Swedish Institute of Computer Science.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 3. Neither the name of the Institute nor the names of its contributors
 *    may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
 *    without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE INSTITUTE AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE INSTITUTE OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
 * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
 * OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
 * OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
 * SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * This file is part of the Contiki operating system.
 *
 */

/**
 * \file
 *         A very simple Contiki application showing how Contiki programs look
 * \author
 *         Adam Dunkels <adam@sics.se>
 */

#include "contiki.h"

#include <stdio.h> /* For printf() */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(hello_world_process, "Hello world process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&hello_world_process);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(hello_world_process, ev, data)
{
  static struct etimer timer;

  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  /* Setup a periodic timer that expires after 10 seconds. */
  etimer_set(&timer, CLOCK_SECOND * 10);

  while(1) {
    printf("Hello, world\n");

    /* Wait for the periodic timer to expire and then restart the timer. */
    PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&timer));
    etimer_reset(&timer);
  }

  PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


From related GitHub-Page regarding the submit that removed .bin and .hex files

The . file (hello-world.simplelink, hello-world.cc26x0-cc13x0, etc.)
is an .elf file.
Seems #2084 was a bit hastily merged. The documentation also states
there should be a .bin and .hex file.

https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/issues/2921
